# How does Idris avoid using dot patterns for inaccessible patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching, idris, agda

In Agda one had to use dot patterns to tell the compiler which parts of a function definition cannot be inspected, in particular which variables can be used for pattern matching and which cannot (in new releases it seems that dot patterns are just optional and one can use new variables instead).

Idris apparently does not use any mechanism of this sort, so how does the idris compiler guess which pattern are accessible and which are not in a function definition? How does it get which are the arguments on which pattern match?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Internally, it does have dots, and you can specify them yourself. But it will add them itself for any argument which reuses a variable name, or which it can't match on (for example a function application or type).

Comment: @EdwinBrady nice. So it's able to automatically find inaccessible patterns?!  I should probably take a look to the source code.